# Multi threading and deadlock

Tags: c, multithreading, deadlock

I am making a multi-threaded C program which involves the sharing of a global dynamic integer array between two threads. One thread will keep adding elements to it & the other will independently scan the array & free the scanned elements.
can any one suggest me the way how can I do that because what I am doing is creating deadlock
Please also can any one provide the code for it or a way to resolve this deadlock with full explanation

Comment: No. Post your code rather, so we can help you fix it.

Comment: This question cannot be answered as-is. Close.

Comment: I have no code uptill yet, I am in middle of my analysis and got stuck in it so I need some POC also

Comment: If you have no code, how are you creating deadlock?

Comment: You have only one resource - the array.  How can you dedlock on one resource?

Comment: Just by concept that if 2 threads paralley writing the reader thread will not get chance of reading untill writing is finished and if the reader thread is reading the writer thread will not get chance of writing untill reading is finished

Comment: 'way to resolve this deadlock with full explanation' - almost sounds like an assignment/exam question...

Comment: NOt an examination question. Its a question i encountered it while I was in analysis mode and i am stuck to it

Answer (score 1):

For the threads I would use pthread. Compile it with `-pthread`.

```
#include <pthread.h>

int *array;

// return and argument should be `void *` for pthread
void *addfunction(void *p) {
    // add to array
}

// same with this thread
void *scanfunction(void *p) {
    // scan in array
}

int main(void) {
    // pthread_t variable needed for pthread
    pthread_t addfunction_t, scanfunction_t; // names are not important but use the same for pthread_create() and pthread_join()
    // start the threads
    pthread_create(&addfunction_t, NULL, addfunction, NULL); // the third argument is the function you want to call in this case addfunction()
    pthread_create(&scanfunction_t, NULL, scanfunction, NULL); // same for scanfunction()
    // wait until the threads are finish leave out to continue while threads are running
    pthread_join(addfunction_t, NULL);
    pthread_join(scanfunction_t, NULL);
    // code after pthread_join will executed if threads aren't running anymore
}
```

Here is a good example/tutorial for pthread: [*klick*](http://timmurphy.org/2010/05/04/pthreads-in-c-a-minimal-working-example/)

Comment: Its some how helpful I am upvoting your answer is somehow helpful to me but not exactly

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, you need to look at the frequency and loading generated by each operation on the array.  For instance, if the array is being scanned continually, but only added to once an hour, its worth while finding a really slow, latency-ridden write mechanism that eliminates the need for read locks.  Locking up every access with a mutex would be very unsatisfactory in such a case.

Without details of the 'scan' operation, especially duration and frequency, it's not possible to suggest a thread communication strategy for good performance.

Anohter thing ee don't know are consequences of failure - it may not matter if a new addition is queued up for a while before actually being inserted, or it may.

If you want a 'Computer Science 101' answer with, quite possibly, very poor performance, lock up every access to the array with a mutex.

Comment: There are multiple threads to write in that global array but only one thread to read it and this task is continuous and I am not sure which time which thread is writing or which time reader thread is reading.
So for this do I have to use mutual exclusion for this or some other method to complete this

Answer (score 0):

http://www.liblfds.org

Release 6 contains a lock-free queue.

Compiles out of the box for Windows and Linux.